# How do I get the unique counts using pandas or sql?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am unable to get my required output from this data frame. How do I get the number of unique users for the plan types and months. Thank you!

This is the data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame{'TRAN_MONTH':  {0: '2020-03',
                1: '2020-03',
                2: '2020-03',
                3: '2020-03',
                4: '2020-04',
                5: '2020-04',
                6: '2020-04',
                7: '2020-04',
                8: '2020-04',
                9: '2020-04'},
 
'PLAN_TYPE': {0: 'COMBO 3',
               1: 'COMBO 3',
               2: 'COMBO 4',
               3: 'COMBO 4',
               4: 'COMBO 2',
               5: 'COMBO 2',
               6: 'COMBO 3',
               7: 'COMBO 3',
               8: 'COMBO 4',
               9: 'COMBO 4'},
 
'PRIM_ID':   {0: 10010001,
              1: 10010001,
              2: 10010002,
              3: 10010002,
              4: 20040003,
              5: 20030002,
              6: 10020010,
              7: 10020010,
              8: 20040003,
              9: 20030002}}
```

In essence, I am trying to find the unique users (PRIM_ID) for each plan type and for each month such that I am supposed to get this data frame back.

```
expected_output = pd.DataFrame{'TRAN_MONTH':  {0: '2020-03',
                                   1: '2020-03',
                                   2: ' 2020-04',
                                   3: '2020-04',
                                   4: '2020-04'},
                  
                  'PLAN_TYPE':     {0: 'COMBO 3',
                                   1: 'COMBO 4',
                                   2: 'COMBO 2',
                                   3: 'COMBO 3',
                                   4: 'COMBO 4'},
                  
                 'UNIQUE_USERS':  {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}}
```

I had written the the code below in order to extract the information I wanted but I got all 1s in my UNIQUE_USERS column.

```
SELECT TRAN_MONTH, PLAN_TYPE, COUNT(DISTINCT PRIM_ID) as UNIQUE_USERS FROM question_three GROUP BY PRIM_ID
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['TRAN_MONTH','PLAN_TYPE'])['PRIM_ID'].nunique().reset_index()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a little off, and there are parentheses missing in your data frame creation.

I tested this and it appears to return the result you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql

df = pd.DataFrame({'TRAN_MONTH':  {0: '2020-03', 1: '2020-03', 2: '2020-03', 
                   3: '2020-03', 4: '2020-04', 5: '2020-04', 6: '2020-04', 
                   7: '2020-04', 8: '2020-04', 9: '2020-04'}, 

                   'PLAN_TYPE': {0: 'COMBO 3', 1: 'COMBO 3', 2: 'COMBO 4', 
                   3: 'COMBO 4', 4: 'COMBO 2', 5: 'COMBO 2', 6: 'COMBO 3', 
                   7: 'COMBO 3', 8: 'COMBO 4', 9: 'COMBO 4'},

                   'PRIM_ID':   {0: 10010001, 1: 10010001, 2: 10010002, 
                   3: 10010002, 4: 20040003, 5: 20030002, 6: 10020010, 
                   7: 10020010, 8: 20040003, 9: 20030002}})

sub_data = pandasql.sqldf("""SELECT TRAN_MONTH, PLAN_TYPE, 
                             COUNT(DISTINCT PRIM_ID) as UNIQUE_USERS
                             FROM df 
                             GROUP BY TRAN_MONTH, PLAN_TYPE""", locals())

print(sub_data)
```

Here's the result:

```
  TRAN_MONTH   PLAN_TYPE  UNIQUE_USERS
0    2020-03   COMBO 3             1
1    2020-03   COMBO 4             1
2    2020-04   COMBO 2             2
3    2020-04   COMBO 3             1
4    2020-04   COMBO 4             2
```